# If a thread is sleeping/waiting, can it still be preempted?

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there any way to tell if a thread is sleeping/waiting by monitor/lock/synchronization mechanism, can it still be preempted?

Comment: If it's sleeping, it's not running, so it's already effectively been preempted.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about the design of Linux. Unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place for questions like this. Or maybe cs.stackexchange.com, since it's actually pretty generic to most operating systems.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your advice and info.